# Changing the property of observableObject from another observableObject

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, mvvm, combine

There is a problem of the following nature: it is necessary to create an authorization window for the application, the most logical solution I found the following implementation (I had to do this because the mainView has a tabView which behaves incorrectly if it is in a navigationView)

```
struct ContentView: View {

@EnvironmentObject var vm: AppSettings

var body: some View {
    if vm.isLogin {
        MainView()
    } else {
        LoginView()
    }
}
```

AppSettings looks like this:

```
struct MyApp: App {

    @StateObject var appSetting = AppSettings()
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .environmentObject(appSetting)
        }
    }
}
class AppSettings: ObservableObject {
    @Published var isLogin = false
}
```

By default, the user will be presented with an authorization window that looks like this:

```
struct LoginView: View {
    @StateObject var vm = LoginViewModel()
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                TextField("Email", text: $vm.login)
                TextField("Password", text: $vm.password)
                
                Button {
                    vm.auth()
                } label: {
                    Text("SignIn")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And finally the loginViewModel looks like this:

```
class LoginViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var login = ""
    @Published var password = ""
    
  //@Published var appSettings = AppSettings() -- error on the first screenshot
    //or
  //@EnvironmentObject var appSettings: AppSettings -- error on the second screenshot

    func auth() {
        UserAPI().Auth(req: LoginRequest(email: login, password: password)) { response, error in
            if let err = error {
                // Error Processing
            } else if let response = response {
                Defaults.accessToken = response.tokens.accessToken
                Defaults.refreshToken = response.tokens.refreshToken
                self.appSettings.isLogin = true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

1 error - [Accessing StateObject's object without being installed on a View. This will create a new instance each time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lROot.jpg)

2 error - [No ObservableObject of type AppSettings found. A View.environmentObject(_:) for AppSettings may be missing as an ancestor of this view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WBJVf.png)

I ask for help, I just can not find a way for the interaction of two observableObject. I had to insert all the logic into the action of the button to implement such functionality

In addition to this functionality, it is planned to implement an exit from the account by changing the isLogin variable to false in various cases or use other environment variables to easily implement other functions

The example is deliberately simplified for an easy explanation of the situation

---

Comment: generally, in databases like `Realm` or `Firebase` has a property like `Auth().currentUser()` that returns a boolean that states whether if a user is logged in or not, it would be much simpler if you just use something like that

Comment: also, as far as I can see, you're not using `.environmentObject(appSettings)` in your `ContentView`, try adding this to your `LoginView`, or wrap everything into a `Group { } ` then pass the `environmentObject`

Comment: @GrandSirr, thanks for the answer, but in many other places it is planned to use similar functionality (for example, for alerts: the first property is responsible for a boolean variable, the second for the title - this will allow not to produce boilerplate code, though I don’t know how good this practice is)

Comment: @GrandSirr, i marked .environmentObject at the topmost level, I'll edit the question now so as not to confuse people:

Comment: if I'm not mistaken, you still have to pass the environmentObject to the `LoginView`

Comment: even though you pass the `environmentObject` to the `ContentView`

Comment: @GrandSirr, I tried to pass the environmentObject to the loginView, I still get an error, I think this is due to the fact that property wrappers can only be used in the view layer, of course you can transfer the entire logical part to the same class where the View is located, but this violates the principles of MVVM . It is very strange that very few people on the Internet come across this problem, there is a premonition that I am doing something wrong

Answer (score 0):

I would think using only `LoginViewModel` at top level would be the easiest way to solve this. But if you want to keep both, you can synchronise them with an `.onChanged` modifier.

```
class LoginViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var login = ""
    @Published var password = ""
    
    @Published var isLogin = false
    
    func auth() {
        UserAPI().Auth(req: LoginRequest(email: login, password: password)) { response, error in
            if let err = error {
                // Error Processing
            } else if let response = response {
                Defaults.accessToken = response.tokens.accessToken
                Defaults.refreshToken = response.tokens.refreshToken
                isLogin = true
            }
        }
    }
}

struct LoginView: View {
    @StateObject var vm = LoginViewModel()
    // grab the AppSettings from the environment
    @EnvironmentObject var appSetting: AppSettings
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                TextField("Email", text: $vm.login)
                TextField("Password", text: $vm.password)
                
                Button {
                    vm.auth()
                } label: {
                    Text("SignIn")
                }
                // synchronise the viewmodels here
                .onChange(of: vm.isLogin) { newValue in
                    appSetting.isLogin = newValue
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```